# How do I die to a green slime?

Tags: achievements, crypt-of-the-necrodancer

There's a trophy/achievement for dying to a green slime. However, I can't run into them for damage, even when I've dropped my weapon. How do I get them to kill me?

Comment: Been a while since I last played but can you be pushed into them by one of the jump pads?

Comment: @Kareen I searched and it didn't pop up >:( but yes it's a dupe.

Comment: Yeah, I just randomly found it browsing the tag page.